# HapiJs: Session store on MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session, authentication, hapi.js

I am using [hapi-auth-cookie](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi-auth-cookie) for authentication. Is there any example to store session on Mongo (or) Redis in Hapi like [connect-mongo](https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo) for production app.